# Component OLE DB source has no input

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, ssis, business-intelligence

I am new at doing SQL server data tools on VS 2010. However what I try do is:

1. I have created a textfile and imported it as a flatfile
2. I try to connect the flat file (with the green arrow) with a OLE DB but get the error:

> Component OLE DB source has no inputs, or all of its inputs are
>   already connected to other outputs. You may be able to edit the
>   component to add new inputs to it.

Why do I get this error?

When I open the flat file a have diffrent rows and data in it, so there actually exists data :/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you need to connect to an OLE DB **Destination** not source

Comment: Oh that solved it :) thanks mate. What's the difference between them by the way?

Comment: source is to read from a connection (which is established via connection manager) and destination is to write to a connection (also established via connection manager)